# Adwords API creating campaign

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm new to AdWords API.

I'm trying to understand what the best way to use it for building new campaigns Is it possible to create a new campaign from csv or xml?

Any code example that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not the best way of anyone may be your best way.

All you have to know any of programming language for google adwords client libraries viz. JAVA,C#,VISUAL BASIC,PYTHON,PHP,PERL,RUBY

Rest depends on  efficiency over language. The XML or CSV is just one of many input methods to load data. Adwords API only understand the client libraries mentioned above, and any one library, after modification, should be used to load data and create campaigns.

Hope it helps.